# Can a saddle point have a horizontal tangent plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have saddle points, where the partial derivatives both equal zero, but intuitively it's hard to understand how they could only touch one point on the surface. Please help me brain? Are there horizontal tangent planes at saddle points?

Comment: "they could only touch one point on the surface." What do you mean by that? Do you mean the tangent plane only touches the surface at the point of tangency?

Comment: Look at the arch-example, $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$. A horizontal tangent plane intersecting the graph in two straight lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true that the tangent plane has to touch the surface (locally) at only one point.

For example, consider the "classic" saddle-point example
$$z=x^2-y^2$$

Then the tangent plane at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is just $z=0$, which touches the surface everywhere on the line $x=y, z=0$ in the $xy$-plane (edit: and the line $x=-y$, thanks @Daniel for comment).

---

Generally, the idea of "tangency" is not always synonymous with "touching at a single point". Consider the graph of $y=x^3$, which has a saddle point at $x=0$. The tangent line $y=0$ sort of "touches" the graph, but it also "cuts" the graph depending on how you look at it.

Let me know if this answers your question!

Comment: It does, thanks for helping me understand!

Answer (score 1):

For any differentiable manifold $M$, the tangent space $T_pM$ is defined at **every** point $p$.  For curves, $T_pM$ will be a line, and a plane for surfaces.

One way of thinking about tangency is as follows:  Suppose we are given a manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Then $T_pM$ will be the be $n$-dimensional hyperplane that provides the best possible approximation of $M$ around $p$.

If we look back to one and two dimensions, this is fairly easy to visualize.  The tangent line will give the best linear approximation of a smooth curve at a point, and the tangent plane will give the best approximation of a surface locally around a point.  Thinking about it in this way can possibly prevent some confusion.

It's important to note that these tangent lines and tangent planes do not necessarily touch the manifold only at a single point, *even locally*.  One trivial example would be the tangent plane to a plane (which is just the plane itself, of course).